# How to call TextToSpeech from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, text-to-speech, android-broadcast

I my app I'm calling a Broadcast Receiver to read incoming Text Messages and say it aloud. My Broadcast Receiver gets called properly, it reads the text message properly but when it comes to the `speak()` method, it just crashes. Here's my code:

This is the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class DrivingModeSpeaker extends BroadcastReceiver  {

            @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int n;
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        Object messages[]=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage smsMessage[]=new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for(n=0;n<messages.length;n++)
        {
            smsMessage[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])messages[n]);

        }
        //show first message
        String sms1=smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();
        String from=smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress();
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(context,"In DrivingModeSpeaker BR",1);
        toast.show();
        DrivingMode.speakSMS(sms1);

    }


}
```

And this is DrivingMode.java which contains the `speak()` method:

```
public class DrivingMode extends Activity {
    private static TextToSpeech myTts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.message_m);
        myTts = new TextToSpeech(this,ttsInitListener);


    }

private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener ttsInitListener=new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int version) {
            // myTts.speak(""+o, 0 ,null);

        }
    };
    public static void speakSMS(String sms)
    {
        myTts.speak(sms,0,null);

    }


}
```

I have tried out this code in a separate project, it works. But in my main project, it doesn't - could it be because of two broadcast receivers clashing or something? I dunno, I'm new to Android, please help!

Comment: stack trace of your logcat?

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are trying to call Activity method by Creating an instance of Activity which through `NullPointerException` if Activity is not running. so instead of calling Activity's method start Activity from `BroadcastReceiver` and send sms data using `Intent.putExtra` as :

For Example :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
       // Your code here....
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(context,"In DrivingModeSpeaker BR",1);
        toast.show();
        // start Activity here
        Intent intent  = new Intent(context,
                    DrivingMode.class);
            intent.putExtra("sms", sms);  //<<< put sms text
            context.startActivity(intent);   

    }
```

and in `DrivingMode` onCreate method get sms data and call `speakSMS` method as :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.message_m);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        myTts = new TextToSpeech(this,ttsInitListener);
        DrivingMode.speakSMS(extras.getString("sms"));

    }
```

also use [TextToSpeech.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html) for finishing Activity  at the end of Speak